# Multiple router setup with an ethernet router and a wireless router

Tags: router, lan

I have the following situation.

1. Main router (EdgeRouter 4) connected to my cable modem (no Wifi capability in this modem). I want to use this router for as much as possible since it is a really good router.

   - LAN IP is 192.168.1.1 with DHCP enabled
   - WAN IP is automatically retrieved from ISP Cable Modem
2. ASUS Wireless Router (want to use this for only wireless clients)

   - LAN IP: 10.0.0.1 with DHCP is set up to give out 10.0.0.x addresses
   - WAN IP: 192.168.1.40 (WAN Port is LAN port on EdgeRouter)

LAN and wireless clients are working OK except that I can't print from Wired devices (192.168.1.x) to the Wireless printer (10.0.0.113)

Ideally, I would like to have all wireless and wired devices on the same network for file sharing, printing etc.

What is a good solution for this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Consider hooking up a LAN port on each router to a LAN port on your modem.  Assign a static IP on the modem for these devices if you can. Turn DHCP OFF on these devices. Now they are on your network, all will connect and you can print. I do this myself and it works well

Comment: You beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

If your wireless router has a "Bridge" or "Access Point" mode you can set that up.  This will disable the DHCP server (and probably the NAT) on the wireless router so devices share IP addresses in the same range and can see each other.  If you wanted the isolation of separating the networks then Google Cloud Print may become your only option to access this printer.

Answer (score 0):

As for as I understand, you got two DHCP servers turned on (one in each router). This is usually not a valid configuration on the same LAN (unless you configure the router to bridge the different IP ranges which you didn't otherwise it would work).

I would suggest to turn off the DHCP in the ASUS Wireless Router and connect it to the EdgeRouter through a regular LAN port (not the WAN port). This way all your devices will get an IP address in the 192.168.1.X range from your Edge router (your ASUS router will only act as a wireless access point) and will be able to communicate with each other.

The second option is to setup your routers to resolve the IP addresses properly. But this is more complicated and doesn't give any advantage - at least none that I see unless you did not mention it in your question.

Comment: But it's _not_ on the same LAN according to OP's question (the networks being separate precisely because OP used the "WAN" port on the 2nd router), so the configuration is perfectly valid.

Comment: @grawity technically you are right, but I don't think that is relevant for this question. He says that he wants to have "all devices on the same network". And even if he specifically does want to cascade the routers for some reason, that's why I included the second option.